# Create a log for all SQL action in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm currently having a problem at work.
Someone in the is modifying the table directly.
For example in my database I have school names like ETS. Well, today it was named Polytechnique.

What I'm trying to tell who did this modification either by his/her IP address or any other way. I currently have no ideas on how to proceed.

What I would like is just the beginning of a solution as to let me figure a part of it . I sadly don't have any ideas for the moment.

Thank you (I'm sorry for any errors english is not my first language. Also I could be mistaken for the tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Welcome to SO.  Sorry no one answered your question yet. It almost never takes this long.)

The short answer is: No. There is no way to find out who was modifying your tables directly.  Access does not have any kind of automatic change logging, and you cannot create any logging procedures in VBA that will monitor manual changes to the tables.

One of the requirements for Access as a front-end is that you trust your end-users to not open tables and edit the data directly.

To prevent this in the future, here are some options:

1. Right click on your table to hide it. However, the user can just unhide it if they know it is there.
2. In your Access db is an option called "Display Navigation Option".  Disabling this will hide the side-bar so the user can't see the tables.  However, pressing F11 will still display them again. This can be easily googled, so I don't recommend it if your users are motivated.
3. Store your data in a SQL server and use connection strings (not direct links) to retrieve and store information.
4. Distribute your Access db via Sharepoint.  The user will only be able to access the forms you specify and will have no direct access to the tables.
5. Consider another software package for your problems.

Comment: @FranckMetis, glad to be of help.  If you are interested in a long term solution that doesn't take too many resources, I suggest #3 above.  It's reasonably secure and still lets you keep an Access front-end.